# Python - reduce ,two dimensional array

Tags: python

I 'm trying to use *reduce* on two-dimensional array which consists of coordinates.I don't have a lot of experience with *reduce* .I have a function called **func** and I have to apply this function to each element of the array. For example:

```
func=lambda x:x-1
array=[[5,9],[10,3]]
reduce (lambda x,y: ...,array)
OUTPUT should be -> [[4,8],[9,2]]
```

I just decrement each element by 1 . Thanks.

Comment: Has your question been answered? Any problems left?

Answer (score 4):

`reduce` takes a function of two arguments and applies it cumulatively to the elements of a sequence - but all you want to do is subtract one from every element of every sublist, so I'm not sure why you would want to use `reduce` here.

I suggest this list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [[5,9],[10,3]]
>>> [[x-1 for x in sub] for sub in lst]
[[4, 8], [9, 2]]
```

Or if you want to use your lambda function:

```
>>> [map(lambda x: x-1, sub) for sub in lst]
[[4, 8], [9, 2]]
```

I find the first one to be more readable, though.

Comment: Great! I don't know why I wanted to use reduce actually. Thank you for your idea :-)

Comment: In general, use `reduce()` when you want "an answer." If you want to "do something to the list" then you don't want reduce - you want `map()` or a comprehension or one of the `itertools` or `functools` functions.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use reduce to decrease each element's value.

 Try using map

```
arr = map( lambda x:[x[0]-1,x[1]-1],arr)
```